# Sequential characterization of limits in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question

**Sequential characterization of limits:**

Let $I$ be an open interval, $a \in I$, and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$, then:

$\\$

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L \text{ if and only if }\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = L \text{ for every sequence }x_n \in I - \{ a \} \text { satisfying } \\ x_n \to a \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

$\\$

---

By any chance, do any of you know the statement of the characterization of limits in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Or maybe a book, website, or any other reference where I can see the statement. I've already tried to search it on the internet, but so far I haven't been able to find the version in $\mathbb{R}^n$, only the version for $\mathbb{R}$, which I'm already familiar with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's the same in any metric spac

Comment: $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=a$ means for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $K$ such that $k>K$ implies $\|x_k-a\|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Nothing really changes, and you should try to prove it

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, 926356?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $||\cdot||$ is the 2-norm, right? I.e, the "standard" norm. Also, I assume it hold for any p-norm, right?

Comment: All norms on ${\bf R}^2$ are equivalent so it doesn't matter which one you take. For general metric spaces, one should write $d(x_k,a)$ instead of $\|x_k-a\|$, and you might have different collections of convergent sequences for different choices of metric.